# How to remove 1000-row limit in MySQL Workbench queries?

Tags: mysql

During execution of an SQL Query in MySQL Workbench, the query is automatically limited to 1000 rows. How does one prevent the tool from imposing this limit?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

<strike>You need to add your own `LIMIT` clause to then end of your query.</strike>

Use a number greater than the possible number of items that will be returned, say `LIMIT 100000`.

**Source:** http://wb.mysql.com/?p=230#comment-1279

---

### Update:

*(Using version 5.2.29CE, not sure how up to date I am):*

On the menu bar visit `Edit` -> `Preferences`.

Jump to the `SQL Queries` tab.

In the `Query Results` section at the bottom untick the `Limit Rows` option.
You can adjust the limit to a higher value from this location as well, if that is preferable.

---

### Update:

*(Using version 6.3.4.0.828)*

On the menu bar visit `Edit -> Preferences`.
Expand `SQL Editor`.
Select `SQL Execution`.

In the **SELECT Query Results** section, you can either uncheck **Limit Rows** or increase/decrease the **Limit Rows Count**.

[image: workbench preferences]

Comment: @BOB: You might actually want to post this as your own answer - its substancially different from the original answer, and well, this worked at *some* point

Comment: The `SQL Queries` tab is named `SQL Editor` in 5.2.38, and is named `SQL Execution` in version 6.2.

Comment: thanks for including both the SQL way and the menu way, I used the SQL way for a one-time export.

Comment: Thanks for the clear, concise answer.  This works exactly as specified (as of November 22, 2012 edit) for MySQL Workbench 6.0.

Answer (score 8):

Version 6.0 on Mac

Menubar->Query->Limit Rows->Don't Limit

[image]

Comment: Yes, works also for windows.